# Is there a way to get Adobe Acrobat Professional on Mac OS X to stop asking to be the default PDF viewer?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

Every time I open Acrobat on OS X 10.5, Acrobat asks to be the default PDF viewer, with no option to "remember this choice" or "not ask again" etc., and I can't find anything in the preferences either to disable asking, but it's quite rude as I have made it perfectly clear that I prefer Preview to open my PDFs!

Comment: I just launched version 9 and it did no such thing.

Comment: Indeed I just opened Acrobat 9 on OS X 10.6 and you are correct. Problem solved--thanks! Any way I can accept a comment as an answer? Or can you repost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hasaan mentinoed in the comments that launching version 9 did no such thing.

Comment: The OP waited half a year for Hasaan to post his comment as answer, before he answered himself. @Philip in the future, mention a user's name if you want them to see your follow-up comment.

Comment: @DanielBeck Good advice way back when, now we have this though: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking *yes* to see if Acrobat remembers the settings, then ctrl-click on a pdf file, choose "Get Info".
From there, select your preferred software under "Open with:", then click the "Change All…" button.

If that doesn't work, maybe Acrobat preferences are corrupt and you should try deleting them.

Comment: Interesting idea, but Acrobat was unfortunately smarter...it checked after I changed them back to Preview and asked again. >:|